# Как склонять сербские блюда, вошедшие в русский язык? И прямая речь!

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, заимствования

И помогите, пожалуйста, - на своё усмотрение - разбить и закавычить реплики, я уже там напортачила... Кто что говорит-спрашивает-отвечает?

Запуталась с тире и кавычками - общие у реплик и перечисляемых блюд. Где-то они вообще не нужны, куда их плодить... Вся пунктуация гуляет как хочет.

> ...Открыли меню – и глаза у нас разбежались. Мы силились разобрать
>   названия сербских блюд – искали однокоренные слова. Но одно дело
>   пытаться вникнуть в эту близкую нам устную речь, другое – отличить
>   «лесковачка мучкалицу» от «плескавицы». Мы по очереди выдвигали
>   различные теории. «Лесковачка – может, означает что-то из леса?» – «И
>   замученное?» – «Да нет! Дичь в муке». – «А плескавица, в этом случае,
>   что ты хочешь сказать?» – «Рыба!» – «Ну да. И тогда «ржаници» - это
>   ржаные сухарики». – «А «печенье»?» – «Печенье и есть. Или что-то из
>   пшеницы? Но тогда что они все вместе делают на одной странице?!» –
>   «Видишь, тут написано «Главна ела». – «Хозяйка все съела?» – «Нет! Это
>   второе, главные блюда…» Наши страдания прервал весёлый усатый мужчина
>   с полотенцем через одну руку наперевес, точно мультипликационный
>   герой, олицетворяющий внимание и угодливость. От него вкусно пахло
>   свежим хлебом и уже опробованной нами «дуней». Глядя на наши
>   измученные интеллектуальными усилиями лица, он рассмеялся и пошёл к
>   буфету. Налил ракии, подмигнул, вернулся к столу, дождался, пока мы
>   чуть пригубили, и неожиданно вскрикнул: «Живели!» Это самый красивый
>   тост, который мне только известен! Столько в нём радости, света,
>   надежды, благого пожелания! Он означает – живём! Будем жить! Будем
>   здоровы! И пей до дна! Всё одновременно. Мы рассмеялись, выпили до
>   дна, и теперь наш официант ткнул кривоватым мозолистым пальцем в
>   надпись: «Чевапчиччи» и снова подмигнул. – «Чевапчиччи», – хором
>   прочитали мы. Он потёр свои руки, словно тщательно вымыл под быстрой
>   струей воды: «Пита? Погачу?» – «Пита-погачу», – заворожённой
>   скороговоркой повторили мы. Он недоверчиво покачал головой и
>   перелистнул меню на первую страницу. «Чорба, айвар, туршия?» Мы
>   согласно закивали. «Шопский салат», – неожиданно выкрикнул он, словно
>   проверяя нашу бдительность. Тут уж мы откинулись на стульях и
>   осознанно согласно кивнули: «Салат какой-то. Нам точно подойдёт». А
>   дальше начался кулинарный беспредел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыли меню — и глаза у нас разбежались. Мы силились разобрать названия сербских блюд — искали однокоренные [*однозвучные? похоже звучащие?*] слова. Но одно дело — [добавлено тире] пытаться вникнуть в эту близкую нам устную речь, другое — отличить «лесковачк**у** мучкалицу» [склоняем оба слова] от «плескавицы». Мы по очереди выдвигали различные теории.
— Лесковачка — что-то из леса?
— И замученное?
— Да нет! Дичь в муке.
— А плескавица? В этом случае что ты хочешь сказать?
— Рыба!
— Ну да. И тогда «ржаниц**ы**» — это ржаные сухарики. [граница — границы; синица — синицы]
— А «печенье»?
— Печенье и есть. Или что-то из пшеницы? Но тогда что они все вместе делают на одной странице?! [ржаницы — пшеницы — странице... *Но тогда почему они в одном разделе?!*]
— Видишь, тут написано «Главна ела».
— Хозяйка все съела? [*— Главная всё съела?*]
— Нет! Это второе... Главные блюда...
Наши страдания прервал весёлый усатый мужчина с полотенцем через руку, [*с полотенцем через одну руку наперевес* — тяжело, "лишнесловно"] точно мультипликационный герой, олицетворяющий внимание и угодливость. От него вкусно пахло свежим хлебом и уже опробованной нами «дуней». Глядя на наши измученные интеллектуальными усилиями лица, он рассмеялся и пошёл к буфету. Налил ракии, подмигнул, вернулся к столу, дождался, пока мы чуть пригубили, и неожиданно вскрикнул: «Живели!»
Это самый красивый тост, *который я слышала, — столько в нём радости, света, надежды!* [благого пожелания] Он означает — живём! **б**удем жить! **б**удем здоровы! И пей до дна! Всё — [добавлено тире] одновременно.
Мы рассмеялись, выпили как надо [опять — до дна?], и теперь наш официант ткнул кривоватым мозолистым пальцем в надпись «Чевапчиччи» [без двоеточия] и снова подмигнул.
— Чевапчиччи, — хором прочитали мы.
Он потёр свои руки, словно тщательно вымыл под быстрой струей воды.
— Пита? Погачу?
— Пита-погачу, — заворожённой скороговоркой повторили мы.
Он недоверчиво покачал головой и перелистнул меню на первую страницу:
— Чорба, айвар, туршия?
Мы согласно закивали. «Шопский салат!» [воскл. знак, если выкрикнул] — неожиданно выкрикнул он, словно проверяя нашу бдительность. Тут уж мы откинулись на стульях и *осознанно-согласно закивали*: «Салат какой-то. Нам точно подойдёт».
А дальше начался кулинарный беспредел.

Answer (score 2):

```
 другое – отличить «лесковачка мучкалицу» от «плескавицы»
```

Мне кажется, если мы начали вставлять сербские слова в русскую речь, то нужно согласовывать и определения:

"...другое – отличить «**лесковачку** мучкалицу» от «плескавицы»"

Вариант пунктуации:

Мы по очереди выдвигали различные теории. **«Лесковачка, может, означает что-то из леса?»** – «И замученное?» – «Да нет! Дичь в муке». – **«А плескавица  в этом случае - что ты хочешь сказать?»** – «Рыба!» – «Ну да. И тогда «ржаници» - это ржаные сухарики». – «А «печенье»?» – «Печенье и есть. Или что-то из пшеницы? Но тогда что они все вместе делают на одной странице?!» ........................................................ Он означает – живём! Будем жить! Будем здоровы! И пей до дна! Всё одновременно. Мы рассмеялись, выпили до дна, и теперь наш официант ткнул кривоватым мозолистым пальцем **в надпись (**убрать двоеточие**)«Чевапчиччи» и снова подмигнул. (**убрать тире)** «Чевапчиччи», – хором прочитали мы. Он потёр свои руки, словно тщательно вымыл под быстрой струей воды: «Пита? Погачу?» **(убрать тире, т.к. здесь есть слова автора)** «Пита-погачу», – заворожённой скороговоркой повторили мы. Он недоверчиво покачал головой и перелистнул меню на первую страницу:**(слова вводят прямую речь, поэтому двоеточие)** «Чорба, айвар, туршия?» Мы согласно закивали. «Шопский салат», – неожиданно выкрикнул он, словно проверяя нашу бдительность. Тут уж мы откинулись на стульях и осознанно согласно кивнули: «Салат какой-то. Нам точно подойдёт». А дальше начался кулинарный беспредел.